# To get subtring from a string

Tags: sql, oracle11g, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am having issue to extract substring from string.
The input values are like

```
{Resultset: 234, edf, ejj, Resultvalue: hsh, 23,hhs}
{ hashvalue: 233, ehdh, Resultset: 2dd34, edf, ejj}
3rd value:
{hashvalue: 233, ehdh, Resultset: 2dd34, Resultvalue: hsh, 23,hhs}
4th value
{hashvalue: 233, ehdh, Resultset:, Resultvalue: hsh, 23,hhs}
5th value
Null
6th value
{hashvalue: 233, ehdh, Resultvalue: hsh, 23,hhs}
```

Output should be like

```
Resultset: 234, edf, ejj
Resultset: 2dd34, edf, ejj
Resultset: 2dd34
Resultset:
Null
Null
Like this.
```

I tried but the expected string sometimes comes at first and sometimes at last. Sometime i get more than expected string.

I think, need regular expression to search for two characters and when first `:` appears don't go for second `}`

Comment: Will each string only contain one "Resultset:" string?

Comment: Yes Gary, it may not contain and if contain only one resultset in a string

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` for this. Look for the string 'Resultset' followed by several non-comma, then one comma, then several non-comma, then one comma, then several non-comma.

```
regexp_substr(colname, 'Resultset[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*')
```

Comment: Then how do you know where to stop? For `Resultset: 234, edf, ejj, Resultvalue: hsh, 23,hhs`, is the result set `Resultset: 234` (no comma) or `Resultset: 234, edf, ejj, Resultvalue: hsh` (3 commas) or what else? What rule do you want to stipulate? Take the string until you find a comma an upper case character or hit the end of the string? Or how else would you define the rule?

Comment: It is a json column value start with { and multiple set of values like set1: s, d, set2: a,k,j}. We want set 1 values. It can come any order. It can come after set 2 also. But the column value start with{ and end with}

Comment: Every set we can identify when it starts with :

Comment: Thorsten, your query works in snowflake but the result also extract all the attribute after researchtitle as well. for ex the input value is,
'{ "sport":"Ice Hockey", 
"researchtitle":"200217 - NBCS CA - Panthers vs. Sharks", 
"authentication-type":"adobe-pass", 
"data":"Panthers vs. Sharks (NBCS CA)|CSNCalifornia", 
}'

and the expected output is 200217 - NBCS CA - Panthers vs. Sharks
but i get the output as
researchtitle":"200217 - NBCS CA - Panthers vs. Sharks", 
"authentication-type":"adobe-pass", 
"data":"Panthers vs. Sharks (NBCS CA)|CSNCalifornia",}

Comment: I'm getting NULL for this string, because it doesn't even contain the word 'Resultset'. Anyway, I gave you my answer, when it lokked like you wanted a 'Resultset' followed by a certain number of values. As this is not the case, my answer cannot work of course. There are JSON function available in Oracle as of version 12c. You are still on Oracle 11g, so in my opinion it is a bad idea to try to tackle JSON within that DBMS.

Comment: If you want to do this still, a number of `INSTR`, combined with `SUBSTR` and `LENGTH` maybe, should do the task. Just go step by step. First look for the position of `'Resultset:'`. If found, look for the next `':'` ...

Comment: Can you give a query for the new value?

Comment: No. Just try it yourself. As mentioned: step by step. Look up `INSTR`. Find the position of  'Resultset:'. Then find the position of the next colon. You can work with `CASE WHEN / ELSE` for different situations. Use `SUBSTR` to get the string from 'Resultset:' to wherever. Just try it. It's work, but you should be able to do this.

Comment: Thorsten in this record, 
{Resultset: 234, edf, ejj, 
Resultvalue: hsh, 23,hhs}
after finindg the colon and getting the string until colon how to search for the last comma back from that colon, can you help. there is no option to backward search

Comment: You can find the last comma in a substring with `INSTR(substr, ',', -1)`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it in oracle it works. snowflake doesn't have instr but has regexp_instr. we can't use -1 in regexp

Answer (score 0):

Return the first remembered group of "Resultset: followed by anything (non-greedy)" when that group is followed by another group consisting of [a comma, then zero or more spaces, then 1 or more word characters ending in a colon] OR [a right curly brace].

CAVEAT: REGEXP_SUBSTR() returns NULL if the match cannot be found.  You may want to wrap the call in NVL() and return something if the value is NULL then.

Edit: Updated to reflect your new test data.

```
WITH tbl(ID, str) AS (
  SELECT 1, '{Resultset: 234, edf, ejj, Resultvalue: hsh, 23,hhs}' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '{ hashvalue: 233, ehdh, Resultset: 2dd34, edf, ejj}'    FROM dual  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, '{hashvalue: 233, ehdh, Resultset: 2dd34, Resultvalue: hsh, 23,hhs}' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, '{hashvalue: 233, ehdh, Resultset:, Resultvalue: hsh, 23,hhs}' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, NULL FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, '{hashvalue: 233, ehdh, Resultvalue: hsh, 23,hhs}' FROM dual
)
SELECT ID,
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '(Resultset:.*?)(, *\w+:|})', 1, 1, 'i', 1) resultset
FROM tbl
ORDER BY ID;

         ID RESULTSET                                                         
---------- ------------------------------------------------------------------
         1 Resultset: 234, edf, ejj                                          
         2 Resultset: 2dd34, edf, ejj                                        
         3 Resultset: 2dd34                                                  
         4 Resultset:                                                        
         5                                                                   
         6                                                                   

6 rows selected.
```

Comment: Gary, this gives first set right second gives extra. Can u suggest to find the last comma based on resultset. Note in the  first value resultset appears at start and second value it appears last. Resultset may appear in middle as well.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  Please update your original post with a complete set of test data and the exected output.

Comment: I get the output you expect.I updated my post to show your test data.

Comment: Gary, when i run the query, i get the result as follows,
1. Resultset: 234, edf, ejj, Resultvalue: hsh, 23,hhs
2. Resultset: 2dd34, edf, ejj
3. Resultset: 2dd34, Resultvalue: hsh, 23,hhs
4. Resultset:, Resultvalue: hsh, 23,hhs
5. NULL
6. NULL
it returns the entire string starting from resultset and end of the string.

Comment: I'm on Oracle 12 but this should still work on 11g. Maybe someone else can try and report results.

Comment: Gary, I tried in Oracle it works great. However, as said, in snowflake it gives the above output.

Comment: This is the first I'm hearing about snowflake!  Add that tag to the original post.

Comment: Gary, I added the tag now